# JavaMail doesnt retrieve mail from sender other than Google

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

I'm using javamail libs to develop simple apps to sending encrypted mail via gmail. after travelling and googling everywhere, it is finnaly done. At least until i run it again this night, suddenly it doesnt read any email other from google.

My code is like this

```
public static void check(String host, String storeType, String user,
            String password) {
        try {

            //create properties field
            Properties properties = new Properties();

            properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
            properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
            properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
            Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

            //create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
            Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");

            store.connect(host, user, password);

            //create the folder object and open it
            Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
            Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
            System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

            for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
                Message message = messages[i];
                System.out.println("---------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
                System.out.println("Subject: " + AESencrp.decrypt(message.getSubject()));
                System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
                System.out.println("Text: " + AESencrp.decrypt(message.getContent().toString()));

            }

            //close the store and folder objects
            emailFolder.close(false);
            store.close();

        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It simply show email from google, however there is another 3 email from other address. I didn't understand, last time I run that code, it works flawlessly. Note that im not making any change to the code from last time run success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These JavaMail FAQ entries might help:

- [Why don't I see all my messages when accessing Gmail with POP3?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmailsettings)
- [What are some of the most common mistakes people make when using JavaMail?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes)

Comment: thanks, so the problem is i have to use IMAP. Other way around, we have to set POP3 for all email in gmail.